Memory usage with node js and chunk
I try extract data in chunks in order to reduce memory usage.
The original file size is 2.24MB
The data size that I need to resolve is 0.2mb
But no matter what I do it seems like measuring the concatenated data is almost 2.2MB.
Here my code
function foo(url,sectionToWatchStart,sectionToWatchEnd ) {
  let isDataSectionFound = false;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buffer= "";
    https
      .get(url, function (response) {
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
          if (chunk.includes(sectionToWatchStart)) isDataSectionFound = true;

          if (isDataSectionFound) {
            buffer += chunk;

            if (chunk.includes(sectionToWatchEnd)) {
              isDataSectionFound = false;
            }
          }
        });
        response.on("end", function () {
          
          resolve(buffer); // the measure size of buffer variable is just 0.19MB
          
        });
      })
      .on("error", function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        reject();
      });
  });
}

// Util Func to measure the size:
const mesurMemory = async () => {
  const initialMemoryUsage = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
  const res = await foo();
  const finalMemoryUsage = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
  const memoryUsageForCode = finalMemoryUsage - initialMemoryUsage;
  console.log(`Memory usage for code: ${memoryUsageForCode / (1024 * 1024)}MB`);
};


So as I said , the file size is 2.24MB and the buffer size is just  0.19MB , why the measure func show usage os 2.2MB

Various memory was used in the reading of the file and you've not allowed any time for garbage collection to happen so that unused data can be made available again.

@jfriend00 can you instruct me how to implement?

How implement what?  nodejs will naturally garbage collect the memory that is no longer in use when it no longer has anything else to do (if it's still running).  It's not something you change in your coding.  This is how a garbage collected system works.

Its seems I missing something , cause according my understanding the heap size should be a bit larger than the chunk size , but in this script it seems the heap is a bit smaller than the file size. Now you said "Various memory was used in the reading of the file " you mean that there is minimum memory that allocated to read file regardless the file size? even if file size its about 100 mb or just 10kb? it still allocate same size if it will be used by this script?

You need to learn how a garbage collected language works.  Every chunk you are passed is a new piece of memory and the prior pieces of memory are available for garbage collection when the interpreter gets a chance and when you're done with the prior chunk.  A garbage collected language is not super efficient with short term memory use (you may get memory use spikes), but it generally doesn't have memory leaks (like you can in non-garbage collected languages) because it knows whether you're still holding onto a reference to a piece of data or not without you have to manually "free" memory.
